Password is visible as plain in chome heap memory dump
I am having a web application where I face a vulnerability issue. When taken chrome heap memory dump, I am able to see the password which I entered on the login form. Screen shot from the heapdump is attached here.

Would appreciate of any help to get out from this issue.

Added autocomplete attribute to form tag, login field and password field
Added below meta tags under head

<meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="PRAGMA">
<meta content="private" http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL">
<meta content="no-store" http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL">
<meta content="must-revalidate" http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL">
<meta content="post-check=0,pre-check=0" http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL">
<meta content="-1" http-equiv="Expires">


And in what way exactly do you consider this a vulnerability?

That would be the password that you already entered and therefore already have access to or otherwise know. If an attacker has access to this then you have bigger problems as they already have access to the machine Chrome is running on.

If an attacker has access to the heap memory dumps of the machine of your users, then at that point they probably cannot be stopped whatever you do. The machine should be considered compromised and the safest option would be to cover it in thermite and ignite it. Which is something that's not really within the purview of browsers.

@CBroe Is it not a vulnerability then when user finds that his own password is getting saved in his machine or when he is using in a public system where a system is being used by mutiple users for multiple reasons? Would like to have a clarification on this if this is not a vulnerability.

@VLAZ The term usually used is "nuke from orbit"

"or when he is using in a public system where a system is being used by mutiple users for multiple reasons?" - do you think this password stored in memory "survives" closing and re-opening the browser? If not, then users not behaving recklessly, should not have a problem either.

@CBroe It looks like that. Even when I closing and opening the browser/tab, it is keeping that password. Sometimes, it is keeping some other user's password when I am taking dump for a different user.
